# SEDE's suggested edit tables seem to return information about the wrong suggested edit

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, data-explorer

I'm trying to use SEDE to hunt down robo-reviewers, and I've hit a rather nasty snag. I'm using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/177139) to grab all reviews on edits I've also reviewed:

```
select * from SuggestedEditVotes where Id in (select Id from SuggestedEditVotes where UserId=1849664)
```

Quite straightforward.

There's a problem, however: The SuggestedEditId *doesn't work*!

Take for example this row:

[image]

Note that the UserId is mine, and the creation date is 2013. Putting the suggested edit ID into a URL, though, gives this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/723477:

[image]

Three things:

1. I wasn't even around SE at that point
2. Even if I was, I didn't touch that edit
3. The date is in 2012, not 2013

Also, some suggested edit IDs give 404's when plugged in to URLs - something is obviously wrong. Very wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> …something is obviously wrong

The URL you're using! You were looking for [*suggested edit* 723477](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/723477), not [*review item* 723477](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/723477) which happens to be a suggested edit. It's a little confusing, but suggested edits existed before the whole concept of the review queues, so they have a identity all of their own.

Note that Data Explorer does have a [`[Suggested Edit Link]` magic column](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) for this situation. Additionally, the review item source includes the underlying suggested edit ID, which can be useful when [querying the relevant API route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits-by-ids).

Comment: I would say that this really should be documented somewhere, but I guess it's documented now ;). Thanks!